# Using isaplha() and while loop with if condition

Tags: python-3.x

I am still learning python programming. The program that I am trying to do will get the user's name and age. Using while loop, I need to let the user enter again if the user did not enter a numeric value for age. However, it did not give the output that I want. I tried using isalpha() but, I think I am doing it wrong.

For example, if I input a name "John" and age "d", it will let the user input again. However, if I input a name "John" and age "6", the program will loop and ask the name and age again even though the age is a numerical.

This is my code snippet.

```
def getName():
b = input("Enter your name: ")
c = input("Enter your age: ")
return b, c

def dispName():
x, y = getName()
while y.isalpha() == True:
    getName()
    if y.isalpha() == False:
        print("Your name is: ")
        print("Your age is ")
        break

dispName()
```

How can I use the while loop properly to achieve my desired output?

Comment: Note that ``y.isalpha() == False`` doesn't mean ``y`` is a number. It could be ``-``, ``!``, ``"Hello World"`` or any other string where any non-alphabet character occurs. You may want to check ``y.isdigit()`` or ``try:`` to convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def getName():
    b = input("Enter your name: ")
    c = input("Enter your age: ")
    return b, c

def dispName():
    while(True):
        x,y = getName()
        if not y.isalpha():
            break
    print("Your name is: "+x)
    print("Your age is "+y)

dispName()
```